# Spark 2.0 & Scala - Split the Column by regex

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column in Spark Dataframe with values like

```
\64192\164169
\64192\164345
\64192\164190
\34193\164169
```

I am trying to split the string with '\' and get the last string in the same column like

```
164169
164345
164190
164169
```

using '/' in regex is getting tricky, can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using **"\\"** to split data and use the reverse function to ensure to select the last

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

and in IDE import

```
import spark.implicits._

scala> df_v.show
+-------------+
|         test|
+-------------+
|\64192\164169|
|\64192\164345|
|\64192\164190|
|\34193\164169|
+-------------+
scala> df_v.withColumn("folder",reverse(split($"test","\\\\"))(0)).show
+-------------+------+
|         test|folder|
+-------------+------+
|\64192\164169|164169|
|\64192\164345|164345|
|\64192\164190|164190|
|\34193\164169|164169|
+-------------+------+
```

Hope this helps you. let me know if you need any help for the same

Comment: Thanks, this helps

Comment: It works fine in REPL Mode, In .scala program it gives error like                                                             ◾could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,String,VR]
◾not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit impl: breeze.linalg.split.Impl2[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,String,VR])VR in trait UFunc. Unspecified value parameter impl.

Comment: add this import spark.implicits._ in your spark scala application.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val df = Seq("\\64192\\164169").toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.show()
+-------------+
|        value|
+-------------+
|\64192\164169|
+-------------+


scala> df.select(split('value,"\\\\")(1)).show()
+-------------------+
|split(value, \\)[1]|
+-------------------+
|              64192|
+-------------------+
```